# undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass when adding a new field form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure why, but when I add this new line to my teams view I get the undefined method 'empty?' error

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :field_id %><br>
  <%= f.select :field_id, @fields, prompt: "select a field" %>
</div>
```

Here are the models for both team and field

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :field
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

I had to migrate field_id into the teams table here is that

```
class AddFieldIdToTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :teams, :field_id, :integer
  end
end
```

As of now I can to to localhost:3000/fields and create a new field with name and location settings. It's when I go to localhost:3000/teams/new that the error occurs. I'm trying to get a dropdown menu of the fields so that when you create a team it will be associated with what field the team will be playing on. If anymore information is needed let me know. Thanks

edit adding my fields controller

```
class FieldsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_field, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /fields
  # GET /fields.json
  def index
    @fields = Field.all
  end

  # GET /fields/1
  # GET /fields/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /fields/new
  def new
    @field = Field.new
  end

  # GET /fields/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /fields
  # POST /fields.json
  def create
    @field = Field.new(field_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @field.save
        format.html { redirect_to @field, notice: 'Field was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @field }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @field.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /fields/1
  # PATCH/PUT /fields/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @field.update(field_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @field, notice: 'Field was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @field.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /fields/1
  # DELETE /fields/1.json
  def destroy
    @field.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to fields_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_field
      @field = Field.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def field_params
      params.require(:field).permit(:name, :location)
    end
end
```

Comment: What is @fields containing, please post your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@fields should be in you controller

```
@fields = Field.all
```

In form

```
<%= f.select :field_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@fields, "id", "name"),
:prompt => "Select field" %>
```

Replace "name" with the value in the field model you want the user to see when they choose a value from the dropdown menu

Alternative could be this which requires no @fields variable.

```
<%= f.select :field_id, Field.find(:all).collect {|f| [ "#{f.name}", f.id ] }  %>
```

And again change f.name like my previous example

Comment: This will avoid the error, but won't get the results desired without retrieving the fields first...

Comment: I see what I did, thanks to what you were explaining on here. I hadn't put @fields = Field.all.map { |field| [ field.name, field.id ] } into my teams controller. Thanks!

Comment: You are also going to need it in "create", or else when the validations fail, it will show the same error.

Answer (score 1):

you are not setting the @fields variable in the new action of your teams controller